# Javascript Cross browser Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I have programmed a simple Jquery ticker (using a pre-made Javascript) to display tweets and other things.
It is working fine with Firefox, Chrome, IE9/10 but not with IE8 and older versions.
I have no experience with Javascript so I can't find why this append doesn't work with IE8

```
$(settings.dom.wrapperID)
.append('<div style="opacity: 1;" class="tweet_row" id="' + 
        settings.dom.tickerID.replace('#', '') + 
        '"><span><!-- --></span><div id="' + 
        settings.dom.contentID.replace('#', '') + 
        '"></div><div id="' + 
        settings.dom.revealID.replace('#', '') + 
        '"><span><!-- --></span></div></div></div>');
```

Comment: Have a look at http://cutephp.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=34641. Maybe it is IE8 specific

Comment: I doubt that it's the problem, but your `<div>` and `</div>` tags are unbalanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) to problem was solved , `<div> and </div>` tags were unbalanced 
I didn't think this may cause the problem